# How can I summarize 2 specific rows in a dataset? [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

this is a part of my dataset:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLHGP.png)

I would like to sum the 2 rows that present "Trentino Alto Adige" both in order to have one single row, preserving the "Date" column.

I tried to do this using the groupby and sum functions but it does not work.

This is my attempt:
df = df.groupby(["Date"],["Region"]).sum()

The output is:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

How should I rewrite my code? Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Thank you.
Next time I will try to post better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your groupby is not properly written, it should be:

```
    df = df.groupby(["Date", "Region"]).sum()
```

Comment: Great! :) Thank you